# DbContext.SaveChanges(); doesn't give error but does not add entity to database

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext, savechanges

I'm trying to save an entity to my database using this code:

```
    public void Add(object entity)
        {
            DbContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I tested and if something is wrong (e.g. a field of the entity is null that can't be null in the datbase) it gives an error. I filled in all the necesarry fields and called this code. It did not give an error. However, the entity also didn't get added to the database. How can I find out where DbContext.SaveChanges(); goes wrong without an error message?

Below is the code that calls the Add() function.

```
  public void StoreElectronicSignatureType(ElectronicSignatureTypeModel model)
    {
        var RSA = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var parameters = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
        model.modulus = Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Modulus);
        model.exponent = Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Exponent);
        model.privatekey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);

        ElectronicSignatureType electronicSignatureType = new ElectronicSignatureType();
        Entity entity =  GetEntity(model.entity);
        electronicSignatureType.Entity = entity;
        electronicSignatureType.HashAlgorithm = model.hashAlgorithm;
        electronicSignatureType.Exponent = model.exponent;
        electronicSignatureType.Modulus = model.modulus;
        electronicSignatureType.Version = model.version;
        //electronicSignatureType.EntityId = entity.EntityId;
        electronicSignatureType.PrivateKey = StrToByteArray(model.privatekey);
        Add(electronicSignatureType);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if setting the state of an untracked item to Added is right/enough. I think you need something like `context.AddObject(...)`

Comment: And please add a tag like Linq-to-sql or EF, I can't remember all those context variations.

Comment: It works in different applications like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to attach the new entity to the context. Try:

```
context.ElectronicSignatureTypes.Add(electronicSignatureType);
context.SaveChanges();
```